# how insert " in numbers of my json [NODEJS]

Tags: json, node.js, regex, format

## i have a JSON like this:

### `{"name1":123,"name2":123,"name3":123}`

#### i want put "" in numbers To stay like this:

#### `{"name1":"123","name2":"123","name3":"123"}`

Anybody know a nodejs code to do this?

Comment: When you put quotes it is turned into a string so you would have to convert it back by using parseInt

Comment: You can also do JSON.stringify(myJsonObject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Judson Terrel was saying above, you should consider using `JSON.stringify(myJsonObject)`

but if you so desired to use regex, here it is

```
let str = '{"name1":123,"name2":123,"name3":123}';
let result = str.replace(/\b(\d+)/g, "\"$1\"");
console.log (result);   
//console-output =>  {"name1":"123","name2":"123","name3":"123"}
```

Comment: if have a dot in number get some errors like this:
//console-output =>  {"name1":"12";"3","name2":"123","name3":"123"}
//console-output =>  {"name1":"12.3","name2":"123","name3":"123"}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the object is already parsed and stored in a variable somewhere, you can do:

```
Object.keys(myObject).reduce((o, k) => Object.assign(o, { 
  [k]: myObject[k].toString() 
}), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to parse the JSON string to an object using `JSON.parse`, and then convert the object values to string with the `String` function, like this:

```js
var strg = '{"name1":123,"name2":123,"name3":123}';

var obj = JSON.parse(strg);

for (var i in obj){
  obj[i] = String(obj[i])
}

console.log(obj)
```